# exchanging values in <div> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

In my javascript there are two divs that contains some values.

I want to exchange the values in these divs.
Is there any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: anything wrong with just exchanging the two divs altogether?

Comment: @kiran: use `innerHTML` of div element in `JavaScript`. it will work for you.

Comment: @kiran: Honestly, you should try *before* you ask. We are happy to help, but we are not doing your work. We will help you if you have a specific problem.

Comment: in which event u want to exchange values of these div.

Comment: in my survey application if questions can be up and down in that case i nee to manipulate that in UI

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = $('#div1').html();
$('#div1').html($('#div2').html());
$('#div2').html(temp);
```

Comment: @kiran, yes it's jquery. Because you tagged your question with `jquery-ui` it occurred to me that you are using jquery.

Comment: id should followed with a # ??if my div is <div id="ra"> then i should write $('#ra').html(........

Comment: @kiran: Yes. And I suggest you read some documentation about the tools you use: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 1):

If you have other nodes in the divs and want to keep data and event handlers intact:

```
var c1 = $('#div1 > *').detach();
var c2 = $('#div2 > *').detach();

c1.appendTo('#div2');
c2.appendTo('#div1');
```

(or shorter ;))

```
var c1 = $('#div1 > *').detach();
$('#div2 > *').appendTo('#div1');
c1.appendTo('#div2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can reorder the div's (this might be suitable if they are adjacent to each other) using the following:

```
$('#div1').insertAfter($('#div2'));
```