# swapping <div>?

Tags: jquery-ui

this is my sample code

```
<div id="id-1"><div>sampledata</div><span>sampledata</span></div> 
<div id"id-2"><div>sampledata</div><div> smpledata</div></div>
<div id"id-3"><div>sampledata</div><div> smpledata</div></div>
<div id"id-3"><div>sampledata</div><div> smpledata</div></div>
```

i'm having the id of only one div(for example id-3) . i want to swap that `<div>` with next `<div>`, since there is more than one `<div>` inside a `<div>` i cant use a `next()` .

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please explain what you want the result to look like? its hard to keep track of all the divs, what div do you want to swap with what div?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? What is it that you want to accomplish? There is more than one div in each of id-2, id-3 and you're repeating id-3 twice, so I assume the last one is supposed to be id-4, which would also have more than one div inside of it.

Comment: im having a set of divs  i want to swap the div with another div. im having only one divs id. i want to swap that div with next div.

Comment: It seems he wants to swap the order with its next sibling.

Comment: Moving seems to be really popular these days... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906926/replacing-div-tag

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906515/exchanging-values-in-div-tag

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612955/jquery-how-to-move-a-li-to-another-position-in-the-ul-exchange-2-lis  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943140/how-to-swap-html-elements-in-javascript

Comment: sorry , u r right @yads thats id-4

Comment: i tried with $('#id-3').insertAfter(#('#id3).next()).. theres <div> inside my main<div>, this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Well, select div, then find next and `insertAfter` next

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
.innderdiv4{
    backgrournd: green;
}

.innderdiv3{
    background: blue;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function (){
    var div = $('#id3');
    var next = $(div).next();
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to do it"))
    {
        $(div).insertAfter(next);
    }
})
</script>

<div id="container">
<div id="id3">
    <div class="innderdiv3">div 3</div>
    <div class="innderdiv3">div 3</div>
</div>
<div id="id4">
    <div class="innderdiv4">div 4</div>
    <div class="innderdiv4">div 4</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: will next() work in my case im having <div> tags inside the main <div>

Comment: i tried with $('#id-3').insertAfter(#('#id3).next()).. theres <div> inside my main<div>, this is not working

Comment: @kiran just copy my code try it and you can modify it easily and if it did not work then let me know

Comment: @kiran this is working code `$('#id-3').insertAfter($('#id-3').next())` is the code (you got wrong code there) and besides you have error in your html

Comment: @experimentX ; it is not working, if there is no other <div inside  id-3 thn its wrking.

Answer (score 0):

`.next();` **does** select the very next sibling, not the child div elements. However, to ensure that you select the next sibling that is actually a div, you should use `.next("div");`.

```
$("#id-3").before($("#id-3").next("div"));
```

The code above works with the example you gave as long as you change your last div's id to "id-4".

Or, you can copy and paste this code for a working example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Div Swap Test Page</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #id-1,#id-2,#id-3,#id-4 {height: 50px; margin:10px 0; border:solid 1px #000}
            #id-3 {border:solid 1px #D00}
            #id-4 {border:solid 1px #0D0}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="id-1"><div>This is div #1</div><span>I am first.</span></div>
        <div id="id-2"><div>This is div #2</div><span>I am second.</span></div>
        <div id="id-3"><div>This is div #3</div><span>I am third.</span></div>
        <div id="id-4"><div>This is div #4</div><span>I am last.</span></div>
        <p><button id="btn"><span>Swap</span></button></p>
    </body>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $("#id-3").before($("#id-3").next("div"));
        });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```